# Aligning two divs side-by-side

Tags: css, css-float

I have a small problem. I am trying to align two divs side by side using CSS, however, I would like the center div to be positioned horizontally central in the page, I achieved this by using:

```
#page-wrap { margin 0 auto; }
```

That's worked fine. The second div I would like positioned to the left side of the central page wrap but I can't manage to do this using floats although I'm sure it is possible.

I would like to push the red div up alongside the white div.

Here is my current CSS concerning these two divs, sidebar being the red div and page-wrap being the white div:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

#page-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: This got closed as a duplicate even though the "original" is from 2011?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you wrapped your divs, like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
  <div id="page-wrap"></div>
</div>
```

You could use this styling:

```
#main { 
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#sidebar    {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

#page-wrap  {
    width: 600px;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

This is a slightly different look though, so I'm not sure it's what you're after.  This would center all `800px` as a unit, not the `600px` centered with the `200px` on the left side.  The basic approach is your sidebar floats left, but inside the main div, and the `#page-wrap` has the width of your sidebar as it's left margin to move that far over.

**Update based on comments:** For this off-centered look, you can do this:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

With this styling:

```
#sidebar    {
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;    
}

#page-wrap  {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this center everything? I want the white div to remain centered and the nav bar to be pushed alongside it. Sorry, didn't explain that well in the original question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the last paragraph you wrote. Yes, I would like to center just the white div and push the red div alongside it. I would do this by using a negative margin then?

Comment: @Ronnie - Added that option as well, this just positions the sidebar to the left 200px to match it's width, making the parent container `relative` and the sidebar itself `absolute` is what allows this to occur.

Comment: @Ronnie - Yep, you can see a working example of the above here: http://jsfiddle.net/jjRyD/

Comment: the sidebar starts to disappear if the window is smaller than 1000px (600px + 200px for each side), but the content uses only 600px+200px. Is it possible to make it not be centered anymore when the window is between 800px and 1000px? Something like a minimum value for the left margin...

Comment: I got it from buildinternet.com/2009/10/purely-css-faking-minimum-margins (alternate method): Put everything inside a `<div id="wrapper">` and then use: `#wrapper{ text-align:center; padding:0 200px; }`. However, this seems to work only for a minimum left margin... I want to have the sidebar on right.

Comment: For any other CSS noobs out there who skimmed the docs too quickly, the float div must come first in the html...

Comment: Hi if i don't give these two float divs any width (which i needed for many reasons) then what happens is that if right div content is long which exceeds main div's width then right div content goes down of left div so in that case these two divs are not side by side. So plz help what to do.

Answer (score 20):

I don't understand why Nick is using `margin-left: 200px;` instead off floating the other `div` to the `left` or `right`, I've just tweaked his markup, you can use `float` for both elements instead of using `margin-left`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/92t8T/)

```
#main {
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
}

#sidebar    {
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}

#page-wrap  {
    width: 300px;
    background: #0f0;
    min-height: 400px;
    float: left;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
```

Also, I've used `.clear:after` which am calling on the parent element, just to self clear the parent.

Answer (score 12):

This Can be Done by Style Property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {

  display: flex;
}

#main div {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">Red DIV</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDiv">Blue DIV</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Its Result will be :

[image]

Enjoy...
 Please Note: This works in Higher version of CSS (>3.0).

Answer (score 4):

The HTML code is for three div align side by side and can be used for two also by some changes

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">first</div>
  <div id="second">second</div>
  <div id="third">third</div>
</div>
```

The CSS will be

```
#wrapper {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#row {
  display:table-row;
}
#first {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:red;
  width:33%;
}
#second {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:blue;
  width:33%;
}
#third {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:#bada55;
  width:34%;
}
```

This code will workup towards responsive layout as it will resize the

```
<div>
```

according to device width. 
Even one can silent anyone

```
<div>
```

as

```
<!--<div id="third">third</div> -->
```

and can use rest two for two

```
<div>
```

side by side.

Comment: thx that helped, and easily made responsive with @media screen and (max-width: NNNpx) {div#fist{display:table-row;width:100%;}etc}

Comment: where is row id in your code? I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to to do this without the wrapper - div#main. You can center the #page-wrap using the margin: 0 auto; method and then use the left:-*n*; method to position the #sidebar and adding the width of #page-wrap.

```
body { background: black; }
#sidebar    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    margin-left: -230px;
    }

#page-wrap  {
    width: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

However, the sidebar would disappear beyond the browser viewport if the window was smaller than the content.

Nick's second answer is best though, because it's also more maintainable as you don't have to adjust #sidebar if you want to resize #page-wrap.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method would be to wrap them both in a `container div` and apply `margin: 0 auto;` to the container.  This will center both the `#page-wrap` and the `#sidebar` divs on the page. However, if you want that off-center look, you could then shift the `container` `200px` to the left, to account for the width of the `#sidebar` div.

Comment: This sounds like a plan. How would I shift the whole container left by 200px? Thanks for the quick reply.