# How to make two divs float side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make two divs float side by side (namely sliderdiv and main-search) but cant seem to get it.`A fiddle of the same: http://jsfiddle.net/Ar99F/1/

**Mark-up**

```
<div id="homecontent" class="container">
    <div id="homecontent-mid" class="row rounded">
        <div id="homebanner" class="rounded">
            <div class="sliderdiv">Content Goes Here</div>
            <div class="main-search">Search Content Goes Here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#homecontent {
    background: url("images/content-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FAFAFA;
    position: relative;
}

#homecontent-mid {
    background: url("images/bg-stage.png") repeat-y scroll right top #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #BDBCBD;
    min-height: 100%;
    outline: medium none;
    top: -40px;
}

#homebanner {
    background: url("images/bg-stage-shade.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.rounded {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.sliderdiv {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    float: right;
}

.main-search {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: medium solid #D51386;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
```

Please Help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716955/css-layout-aligning-two-divs-side-by-side

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/CbCKM/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar99F/2/)**.
Just put `float: left` to both of them and remove the `clear: both`.

Comment: Note that the container is still collapsed, add `overflow: hidden;` to `#homecontent` as well - http://jsfiddle.net/Ar99F/5/

Answer (score 2):

add `overflow:hidden` to your wrappers to fulfill the design and remove `clear:both;` and you will need to put `float:left` to just the first item not to both

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar99F/16/)**

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ar99F/10/)**

**CSS**

```
#homecontent {
    background: url("images/content-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FAFAFA;
    position: relative;
}
#homecontent-mid {
    background: url("images/bg-stage.png") repeat-y scroll right top #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #BDBCBD;
    min-height: 100%;
    outline: medium none;
    top: -40px; 
    display:table;
}
#homebanner {
    background: url("images/bg-stage-shade.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;

}
.rounded {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.sliderdiv {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;

    display:table-cell;
}
.main-search {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: medium solid #D51386;
    clear: both;
    display:table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
```