# Gridview Column fixed in horizontal direction

Tags: asp.net

I have taken two gridviews in a div and made header fixed and body scrollable but my requirement is to have two columns of both gridview fixed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use Table to sepaerate two divs or just apply css to align the div. For further information refer this link to align the div 
[CSS layout - Aligning two divs side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716955/css-layout-aligning-two-divs-side-by-side[1])