# How can I align two columns horizontally?

Tags: html, css

The columns aren't horizontally aligned :
[image: column]

The problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iokm9.jpg

I want to make 2 columns in my blog:

1. one is the main page of the blog with articles
2. the other one is a menu.

I decided to do that through CSS as I have no other idea how to do that :) (take a look at the code below).

As for my HTML, I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible (take a look at the code below).

How can I align the second column with the other one?

It seems like there's some padding about 20px but it doesn't even exist within my entire code. I swear to god I don't know what to do with this.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 1%;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}


/* Left Column (main) */

.column.main {
  width: 76%;
  background-color: grey;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
}


/* Right Column (menu) */

.column.menu {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column main">
  <div class="card">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column menu">
  <div class="card">
    <h3 align="center">Main Menu</h3>
    <li>Main Menu</li>
    <li>English</li>
    <li>German</li>
    <li>Spanish</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use flex .. that is easy

Comment: What do you mean by flex? I'm not really good at CSS and HTML yet.

Comment: Your <div> tag should be assign CSS classes with correct styles set. HAve a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716955/aligning-two-divs-side-by-side

Comment: See here is flex tutorial if you want to learn about flex.. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS Reset to remove any default margins and also note that your HTML is invalid. `li` must be contained in a `ul` wrapper.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 1%;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
}


/* Left Column (main) */

.column.main {
  width: 76%;
  background-color: grey;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
}


/* Right Column (menu) */

.column.menu {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column main">
  <div class="card">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column menu">
  <div class="card">
    <h3 align="center">Main Menu</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Main Menu</li>
      <li>English</li>
      <li>German</li>
      <li>Spanish</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by setting all your margins to zero.

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Because some HTML elements have predefined margins (`body`, `h1 to h6`, `p`, `fieldset`, `form`, `ul`, `ol`, `dl`, `dir`, `menu`, `blockquote` and `dd`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;
HTML

```
<div class="content">
<div class="main">Content</div>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Message</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
margin: 10px;
padding: 10px;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 90% auto;
grid-gap: 10px;
}
.main {
text-align: center;
background: grey;
}
.menu {
background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try this it will help you to create two columns side by side
HTML!

```
   <div class="row">
   <div class="column"></div>
   <div class="column"></div>
   </div>
```